# pax exam: Resolve fragmented Bundles

Tags: osgi, integration-testing, resourcebundle, pax-exam

Solved!
It was a classpath issue. Thanks

I want to deploy and resolve a fragmented bundle. If I use the method noStart(), the bundle fragment remains in state INSTALLED but I expect the state RESOLVED. Thus, the bundle host can not see its resources. With Apache Felix everything works fine.

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {
   Option[] conf = options(
      systemProperty("org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning").value("4"),
      mavenBundle().groupId("mygroup").artifactId("myfragmentedbundle").version("1.0.0.0").noStart(),
      mavenBundle().groupId("mygroup").artifactId("myhostbundle").version("1.0.0.0").startLevel(3).start(),
      junitBundles());
   return conf;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and Regards!
Roland

Comment: Hard to tell without further information. Fragment bundles do work, see [FragmentTest](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/blob/exam-reactor-3.2.0/itest/osgi/src/it/regression-multi/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/exam/regression/multi/fragment/FragmentTest.java) for an example. Set logging to DEBUG to find out more or use an OSGi console to diagnose missing imports.

Comment: Solved! It was a classpath issue. Thanks